# Install oozie on Hadoop 2.2

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I need some guidance on installing Oozie on Hadoop 2.2. The Quick Start docs page indicates that

> IMPORTANT: By default it builds against Hadoop 1.1.1. It's possible to
>   build against Hadoop 2.x versions as well, but it is strongly
>   recommend to use a Bigtop distribution if using Hadoop 2.x because the
>   Oozie sharelibs built from the tarball distribution will not work with
>   it.

I haven't been able to get Bigtop to work.

I tried following some guidance from [here](http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-build-oozie-with-different.html) but it only tells me to edit the pom.xml files, not what to edit in them.

I have pig and maven installed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the releases resolving shared libraries with Maven, and has been since fixed if you use git master. I had this problem so hopefully this solution will work for the Oozie version you are building from.

The advice at [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oozie-user/201312.mbox/%3CCEDDEB80.76815%25chitnis@yahoo-inc.com%3E) is of use. Similar to the [blog post you linked](http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.ie/2013/04/how-to-build-oozie-with-different.html), the grep command will indicate the offending files:

```
$ grep -l "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT" `find . -name "pom.xml"`
./hadooplibs/hadoop-2/pom.xml
./hadooplibs/hadoop-distcp-2/pom.xml
./hadooplibs/hadoop-test-2/pom.xml
./pom.xml
```

Any mentions of 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT in these files should be replaced with 2.2.0

I would suggest removing the -SNAPSHOT part using the following command:

```
 $ grep -l "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT" `find . -name "pom.xml"` | xargs sed -i 's|2.2.0-SNAPSHOT|2.2.0|g'
```

**UPDATE**: If you don't have Hadoop JARs built from when you built Hadoop itself then you will need to add the option -DincludeHadoopJars

And then build the package:

```
 $ mvn clean package assembly:single -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests
```

Or if you're using JDK7 and/or targeting Java 7 (as I did):

```
 $ mvn clean package assembly:single -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DjavaVersion=1.7 -DtargetJavaVersion=1.7 -DskipTests
```

Documentation on building Oozie (version 4 docs) is available [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/ENG_Building.html).

The above worked building release-4.0.0 with Hadoop 2.2 and Java SDK 7.

The distro can then be found in distro/target.